# Splitting a JSON Array with JQuery that has been returned by PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to JQuery and the whole JQuery to PHP back to JQuery process.

So i have a simple ajax JQuery script:

```
$.ajax({

           type: "POST",
           url: "includes/calc.php",
           data: {

               'var1':var1,
               'var2':var2,

           },
           success: function(data){
               alert(data);
               $("input#hiddenprice").val(data);
               $('#'+itemprice).html("&euro;"+data);

           }

       })
```

This goes to a PHP script and then I return a value, using a simple echo

```
echo $newprice;
```

The success function above uses this as 'data'. This all works and is fine.

But what if I want to return more than one value.

I think I can used `json_encode();`

As I understand it something like:

```
$dataset = array($var1, var2, var3);

echo json_encode($dataset);
```

But say I have two values, how do i put them both into the JSON and then how do I split them on the other end.

So say 'data' is an array, how do I tell JQuery to split it?

Sorry if this is simple

Comment: You can return an associative array, and the json returned should allow you to access `data.key1`, etc. from your jquery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the dataType option for `.ajax()` as `json`, jQuery will automatically parse the JSON string returned by the call into an appropriate javascript object/array.

So your call might look like this:

```
$.ajax({

   type: "POST",
   url: "includes/calc.php",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {

       'var1':var1,
       'var2':var2,

   },
   success: function(data){
       alert(data);
       $("input#hiddenprice").val(data);
       $('#'+itemprice).html("&euro;"+data);

   }

})
```

Now, let's say the response from your PHP script is a JSON string representing an object like this:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

In your success handler you can simply access this as an object like this:

```
   success: function(data){
       alert(data.key1);
       alert(data.key2);
   }
```

Or, if the returned JSON string represents an array like this:

```
["value1","value2"]
```

Then you can access the array values in the success handler like this:

```
   success: function(data){
       alert(data[0]);
       alert(data[1]);
   }
```

If you do not want to add the `dataType` option, you can also opt to manually parse the returned JSON string into an object/array like this:

```
   success: function(data){
       var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
       alert(dataObj.key1);
       alert(dataObj.key2);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({

       type: "POST",
       url: "includes/calc.php",
       datatype : 'json',
       data: {

           'var1':var1,
           'var2':var2,

       },
       success: function(data){
           alert(data.firstvalue);
           alert(data.secondvalue);

       }

   })
```

please look at that datatype. now the respose need to be json.

In your php user json_encode instead of echo.

```
$firstvalue = 'your first value';
$secondvalue = 'your second value';
echo json_encode(array('firstvalue' => $firstvalue,'secondvalue' => $secondvalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to organize data in a JSON object. The simplest is to return a linear array of strings or numbers. Use http://jsonlint.com/ to test your data to see if it's valid JSON, or just feed a PHP array (linear or associative) into `json_encode`.

If `data` is a JSON linear array, you can treat it like any other JavaScript array in your `success` callback:

```
var first = data[0]; // first element
var second = data[1]; // second element
```

Answer (score -1):

implode your php variables with a symbol or any custom data

like

```
$var[0] = '1st variable';
$var[1] = '2nd variable';
$var[2] = '3rd variable';

echo implode('_SPLIT_',$var);
```

Now in jquery success function

split the response with '*SPLIT*'

as

```
 var response = data.responseText.split('_SPLIT_');
 var variable1 = response[0];
 var variable2 = response[1];
 var variable3 = response[2];
```

and assign as your wish

Comment: there is no reason to implode the data array like this.  Just `json_encode()` it.  JSON is a much more common and widely accepted serialization format than this home-hack serialization would be. JSON encoding will also allow you to represent arrays or object or any combination of the two with great ease.

Comment: i think this is the better method method than json_encode and always preferable as a developer who can modify any code in his own style. ultimately the out come should be correct and this is 200% correct code...

Comment: How is this better?  Sure maybe it can be equally applicable for use simple one dimensional arrays, but what happens when you need to start doing things that modern AJAX-driven web applications due like sending objects or arrays of objects.  Your serialization method breaks down really quickly.  For example tell me what steps you need to go through to serialize an object using your approach.  How about an array of objects?